# Wrong datetime in android

Tags: android

I need to get datetime 2015-11-14 11:20

```
Log.d(myLog,new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

But I get 2015-11-13 18:52

Comment: The date format seems the same to me. So, may be you need to check your time source or time zone setting for that gettime().

Comment: I have worked the last 6 months very intensively with the Java Calendar API.
What I noticed is that the week of the year is counted differently on the emulator than on an actual device.
For instance the 20th January of 2019 is week 3 on an actual device but on the emulator it'll return week 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this Code:

```
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        // formattedDate have current date/time
        Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: My date is 2015-11-14 11:54
Your code returns 2015-11-13 19:25

Comment: please check in mobile.

Comment: I use Genymotion for check, i haven't now mobile

Comment: sorry. code is working for me. check  your system time and Genymotion time

Comment: Thank you. It was wrong time zone on my virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Date Method which returns your need:

```
 //Date format MM/DD/YYYY
    private String getTodaysDate() {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        return(new StringBuilder()
                .append(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("/")
                .append(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("/")
                .append(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" ")).toString();
    }
```

Time Method which returns your need:

```
 //Time format HH:MM:SS
    private String getCurrentTime() {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        return(new StringBuilder()
                .append(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)).append(":")
                .append(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)).append(":")
                .append(c.get(Calendar.SECOND)).append(" ")).toString();
    }
```

Comment: Your method also returns 11/13/2015

Comment: then what's the date in your testing device

Comment: code works very well, i think there may be problem of time zone some, check and debug properly, Thanks